# USGS 3DEP 1m issues with quality and Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, dem, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have an issue when layering elevation data using hillshade with USGS 3DEP 1m DEM.

Some areas in the US I get artifact lines(lower quality?) on my hillshade layer, while other areas in the US I get high quality hillshade layer with no artifacts.

Here is the code I have in Earth Engine it is very basic hillshade of elevation data.

```
var elevation = ee.ImageCollection('USGS/3DEP/1m');
elevation = elevation.select('elevation');
var proj = elevation.first().select(0).projection();
elevation = elevation.mosaic().setDefaultProjection(proj);


var elevationVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 4000,
  palette: ['000000', 'ffffff']
};

var hillshadeVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 255,
  palette: ['000000', 'ffffff']
}

var hillshade = ee.Terrain.hillshade(elevation);

Map.addLayer(hillshade, hillshadeVis, "Hillshade");
```

As an example when I look at a location like Winter Park, Colorado it has artifact lines, but when looking at Mount Si in Washington the hillshade layer is clear with no artifacts.

Image comparison here:

[image: Winter Park]

[image: Mount Si]